Verifying shim SBAT data failed: Security Policy Violation - Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
There are a number of threads on this, but my situation appears a little different when I try the suggested resolutions. Yesterday my dual boot pc updated Windows 10. When I tried logging into Ubuntu today, I got the "Verifying shim SBAT data failed: Security Policy Violation" message.
I pressed the Power button, hit F2 repeatedly, and I got to the screen that allowed me to disable Secure Boot, and I saved it. Then it came up with the usual screen to select Windows or Ubuntu, and I select Ubuntu. It looks like Ubuntu might come up, but then it comes back with the screen asking me to select Windows or Ubuntu. So I cannot get Ubuntu up to run the mokutil command that I have read elsewhere. Windows will come up if I select it.
Are there any other methods to get Ubuntu started? Do I have to do a new install?

Are you running an old version of Ubuntu or one that has not been updated? You need the newer shim or turn off Secure Boot.
Since November 2022, several Linux distributions, including Ubuntu 22.04.2 and 20.04.6, have upgraded to shim 15.7, which provides a critical security update to address various vulnerabilities in the boot stack. To address this issue, it is recommended that users switch to newer installer media, such as Ubuntu 22.04.2, Ubuntu 20.04.6, and equivalent updated media from other distributions.
https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/sbat-revocations-boot-process/34996
Using my 24.04 Kubuntu shows slightly newer version:
fred@z170-noble:~$ dpkg -s shim-signed | grep Version
Version: 1.58+15.8-0ubuntu1

Sbat Windows update stops old Linux shim from working
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/august-13-2024-security-update-kb5041160-3e8026f2-bb4c-4c1c-9855-d41e1b5b1bd9
See link below by user user535733
Has details on update, update procedure available after August 29th, 2024. Only applies to dual boot Windows systems with UEFI Secure boot on.

Hello oldfred, I am using 22.04.4, and I accept all the updates. Is there a shim update I can get, and how do I load it? I need simpler guidance. Thank you, Kevin

More info now seems to say you need 15.8. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cd-boot-images-amd64/+bug/2076929 The discourse link above has procedure, but I think that only gives 15.7. Short term fix is just turn off UEFI Secure Boot.

I turned off secure boot and I now have a functioning Windows system, but Ubuntu will not come up. If I install the latest Ubuntu version to overwrite the old one, do you think it would work and can I then turn secure boot back on?

https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/sbat-self-check-failed-mitigating-the-impact-of-shim-15-7-revocation-on-the-ubuntu-boot-process-for-devices-running-windows/47378 seems to confirm your diagnosis that shim 15.8 is required, and promises a fix with the 24.01 respin on 29 Aug 2024.

This was fixed as you suggested. I installed new 24.04.01 over 22.04.04. Maybe everyone else knows, but I had to clear the Ubuntu volume using Windows Disk Manager first before I could install over it. Thank you.
